# Howto upload multiple files using springmvc3 with annotation?

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

I have try this:
MyController.java:

```
@RequestMapping("new")
public void newNotify(Model model,
@RequestParam(value = "doc", required = false) List<MultipartFile> files){
     //blablabla...
}
```

And I use curl to post a request to that url:

```
D:\Software\CURL>curl.exe http://127.0.0.1:8080/new -F"@doc=cookie.txt" -F"@doc=obm.gif" -b cookie.txt
```

But when I debug in the controller I found the files's size is 0.

Should I make the files in a bean?

Update:It is my fault.The file post by curl must be something like -F"doc=@docname.txt".

Comment: I think maybe it is the problem of curl.I try that with a simple jsp page again and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "new", method = { POST, PUT })
public void newNotify(Model model, MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest){
    MultipartFile file = request.getFile("doc");
    //blablabla...
}
```

Comment: It is my fault.The file post by curl must be something like -F"doc=@docname.txt".